# Is there any way to have WebView auto-link URLs and phone numbers in Android?

Tags: android, hyperlink, webview

If a page has a URL or a phone number on it that isn't a link is there any way to have [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) recognize it and automatically turn it into a link like you can with [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)s?

With a `TextView` you would simply set the `android:autoLink` to the desired settings:

```
<TextView
    android:autoLink="web|phone"
    ... />
```

but I can't find any equivalent for `WebView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about any way which would make this work just by changing a setting, but a workaround would be to wait until the web page finishes loading and then do:

```
yourWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){ /* code that creates links */ })()");
```

This will inject javaScript into the already loaded web page.
There's a slightly longer example available here: http://lexandera.com/2009/01/injecting-javascript-into-a-webview/.

You can find the JavaScript source for creating links if you take a look at the source of Linkify script for Greasemonkey (it's a plugin for Firefox in case you're not familiar with it). I believe it comes with the default install.

Comment: Ha... that is exactly the route I was planning (including using Linkify as an example) to take if there wasn't a built in way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the Browser have auto-detection for phone numbers and addresses, though?  There's got to be a simpler way. I just don't know it.

Comment: It does have some sort of address (and possible phone number) detection, yes. But from my experience it's not very reliable (last time I tested it it only recognized US addresses) and it also doesn't highlight what it detects.

Comment: The Linkify greasemonkey script didn't end up working because (apparently) WebView doesn't have XPath. I ended up digging up a bookmarklet that used DOM and (after modification) it worked fine.

Answer (score 35):

If you are loading your own (web) content from a String, then you can do something like this:

```
final String content = "My email is: firstname@email.com ...";
Spannable sp = new SpannableString(content);
Linkify.addLinks(sp, Linkify.ALL);
final String html = "<body>" + Html.toHtml(sp) + "</body>";
myWebView.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: Note that if the content string already contains HTML, you'll want to use `Spannable sp = new SpannableString( Html.fromHtml(content) )` so that your characters aren't entity-ized in `Html.toHtml(sp)`.

Comment: is it works for Lollipop version? I am running my app on both Lollipop and Kitkat but getting problem on Lollipop device?

Comment: This works but the problem with formatting. If content has tags that are not supported(e.g. <li>) by webview.