# Preventing autolinking of emails and URLs in an Android WebView

Tags: android, webview

I have a `WebView` which may contain data that appears to be getting "auto linked".  Something that looks like an email address is becoming clickable, even though it's now within an `<a>` tag or has an `onclick` attribute.  How do I disable this auto-linking?

I've looked thorugh the `WebView` docs, as well as the `WebSettings` docs, but didn't seem to see anything that mentions this behavior.

[alt text http://beautifulpixel.com/assets/5554_Fast-20100706-110228.png](http://beautifulpixel.com/assets/5554_Fast-20100706-110228.png)

Comment: Why do you want to suppress this behaviour? It seems pretty reasonable that all email addresses on a device whose primary purpose is communication should be clickable to send an email...

Comment: I have 100% control over the content of this WebView. and I don't want it doing things I don't tell it to.  If I want an email address clickable, I will make it so.  Also, in my setup, it highlights but is overridden by event handlers that prevent it from actually firing here.  Mainly I want explicit control over this behavior.  Especially since it does D-pad highlighting as well.  And iPhone's `UIWebView` lets you turn it off: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/dataDetectorTypes

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a bit late, but for future reference, this might be a solution that will work regardless if the links are auto created or defined in the `<a>`-tag.

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // return true; // will disable all links

        // disable phone and email links
        if(url.startsWith("mailto") || url.startsWith("tel")) {
            return true;
        }

        // leave the decision to the webview
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To do *all* the email addresses, add a meta tag:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="email=no" />
```

You can also disable physical address and telephone detection:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="address=no" />
```

In my own application, though, I needed [PhD's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9057624/241211) to prevent only one email from being linked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, tried this:

```
<a onClick=\"return false;\">jorgesys@elnorte.com</a>
```

it did not worked.

Then tried this:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);'>800-644-9737</a>
```

and it did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Hi Squeaggy why you do want to eliminate that funcionality from the webview, but well a tricky way would be including  `onClick="return false;"` in the anchor tag  that contains the email or URL.

```
<a onClick=\"return false;\">jorgesys@elnorte.com</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

That appears to be unchangeable functionality of the WebView.

You could do the opposite of this [Is there any way to have WebView auto-link URLs and phone numbers in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744091/is-there-any-way-to-have-webview-auto-link-urls-and-phone-numbers-in-android) and create a javascript link stripper (instead of the proposed link injector there).

Not sure what else would work for this.