# Auto detect phone number, email and URL link at Webview - Android sdk

Tags: android, email, webview

Did anyone know how to auto detect the phone number, email and URL link at Webview? Then user can click on it to popup call function, email apps and web browser just like as iPhone sdk got auto detect function on it at webview.

Can anyone help on it?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401059/having-android-webview-detect-and-popup-email-dialog-or-phone-call-dialog

Comment: old question indeed but am gna give it a try anyway, that function was deprecated in iOS4 and now you may have to let user input their own phone number / per parameter security issues

Answer (score -2):

Read up on the Linkify class [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html).

A snippet from the documentation:

`addLinks(TextView text, int mask)`

Scans the text of the provided TextView and turns all occurrences of the link types indicated in the mask into clickable links.'

Comment: The question is about webview not textview.