# Link phone numbers for Android?

Tags: android, phone-number, tel

In my Android app, I have a website in WebView (URL) with many phone numbers. But the numbers don‘t offer click-to-call. Do I have to link all number on my website with `tel:123456789`?

In my iOS-App click-to-call is available without linking the phone numbers. Can I do it in Android webview, too? Thanks for every answer.

Comment: Not sure if there is a way around. I think you might need to use `tel:`. Lets wait for more answers. Check [Is there any way to have WebView auto-link URLs and phone numbers in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744091/is-there-any-way-to-have-webview-auto-link-urls-and-phone-numbers-in-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to have WebView auto-link URLs and phone numbers in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744091/is-there-any-way-to-have-webview-auto-link-urls-and-phone-numbers-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your textview:

```
android:autoLink="phone"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have a WebView. How can I do this? Where to add: android:autoLink="phone"?